# SQL Server looping query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I made this view in sql server to combine the values of 2 records of multiple columns. But the problem with this solution is that you need a concat for every column in table2. I would like to know if it is possible to do the concat part with a loop and a dynamic variable for the column numbers (columns in table2 are called 1,2,3,4,5....) of table2.

```
SELECT 
dbo.table1.lot_id AS lot,
dbo.table1.hybird_id AS hybrid,

concat( 
    LEFT( (SELECT dbo.table2.[1] FROM dbo.table2 WHERE dbo.table2.parentals_id = dbo.table1.parental_male_id AND dbo.table2.lot_id = dbo.table1.lot_id) , 1),  
    LEFT( (SELECT dbo.table2.[1] FROM dbo.table2 WHERE dbo.table2.parentals_id = dbo.table1.parental_female_id AND dbo.table2.lot_id = dbo.table1.lot_id) , 1)
) AS '1', 

--above concat x31 times more

FROM dbo.table2
INNER JOIN dbo.table1 ON dbo.table2.lot_id = dbo.table1.lot_id
GROUP BY dbo.table1.lot_id, dbo.table1.hybird_id, 
dbo.table1.parental_male_id, 
dbo.table1.parental_female_id
```

I tried a few things but nothing worked, any ideas?

Comment: MySQL cannot also be SQL-Server. Tag the correct rdbms please. You could do this with dynamic SQL. But big red flags are going off here as to why you need to concat all of the columns in a table to begin with.

Comment: If this is going to be a view you will only have to type it out once.  That might take less time than trying to be clever.

Comment: why do you need the sub queries to begin with? Can you post a sample data and expected output?

Comment: Something in your table design seems horribly wrong here. The fact that you have columns named 1, 2,3 etc is an indication that you have repeating groups which violates 1NF and causes all sorts of problems like the one you are facing here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to simplify it a bit, kind of

```
SELECT lot, hybrid, parental_male_id, parental_female_id
    concat(Left(m.[1],1), left(f.[1], 1)) AS [1] 
    --,.. 
FROM (
    SELECT dbo.table1.lot_id AS lot
        , dbo.table1.hybird_id AS hybrid
        , dbo.table1.parental_male_id
        , dbo.table1.parental_female_id
    FROM dbo.table2
    INNER JOIN dbo.table1 ON dbo.table2.lot_id = dbo.table1.lot_id
    GROUP BY dbo.table1.lot_id, dbo.table1.hybird_id, 
       dbo.table1.parental_male_id, 
       dbo.table1.parental_female_id
     ) t  
JOIN dbo.table2 m ON m.parentals_id = t.parental_male_id AND m.lot_id = lot)  
JOIN dbo.table2 f ON f.parentals_id = t.parental_female_id AND f.lot_id = lot)
```